# Json having repeated key name in different node

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, key

I am working in json. In json data key is repeated in different node in single json. it is a response json. how can i make a serialized class for this json class.
In below json data is repeated is different node. when i tried online class generator, the class generated not having second data class. how we solve it.

```
{
  "frost": {
    "response": {
      "status": {
        "message": "succe"
      },
      "totalRecords": 2,
      "data": [
        {
          "abc": "a1",
          "xyz": "te"
        },
        {
          "abc": "e5",
          "xyz": "pe"
        }
      ]
    },
    "request": {
      "method": "htl",
      "data": {
        "name": "raja",
        "partnerTypeId": "3",
        "resultType": "json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us what have you tried so far and where did you stuck. I also encourage you to visit https://json2csharp.com/ as a good starting point for creating classes from a sample json.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this by hand it to attack each portion.  For example, `response` is a class that has a `status` which is a class, a `totalRecords` (an integer) and a `data` which is an array of class instances.  When I went through this exercise, I came up with these classes (from top to bottom overall, but from the bottom up in terms of depth):

```
public class ResponseDataItem
{
    public string abc { get; set; }
    public string xyz { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseStatus
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public ResponseStatus status { get; set; }
    public int totalRecords { get; set; }
    public List<ResponseDataItem> data { get; set; }

}
public class RequestData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string partnerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string resultType { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string method { get; set; }
    public RequestData data { get; set; }
}

public class Overall
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Overall frost { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I just deserialized your JSON into an instance of `Root`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(theJson);
```

You may want to use `[JsonProperty]` so that you have C# standard property names, something like:

```
public class ResponseDataItem
{
    [JsonProperty("abc")]
    public string Abc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("xyz")]
    public string Xyz { get; set; }
}
```

and you may want to rearrange things (and, you may want to use Dictionaries in some places), but this should work for what you show.